# Alternative to operator()() overloading? || Direct member access

Tags: c++, operator-keyword, raii, conversion-operator

I would like to wrap C types into a CPP class for better memory handling. For instance the below code snippet shows roughly what I would like to do:

```cpp
class TJCompressor
{
public:
    TJCompressor()
        : m_tjInstance(tjInitCompress())
    {
        if (m_tjInstance == nullptr)
            throw std::runtime_error("Could not create a TJ compressor instance");
    }
    ~TJInstance()
    {
        tjDestroy(m_tjInstance);
    }

    const tjhandle& operator()() const
    {
        return m_tjInstance;
    }

private:
    tjhandle m_tjInstance = nullptr;
};
```

However, now I need to access the actual tjhandle through `operator()()` and I would prefer to get rid of this.

```cpp
TJCompressor compressor;
tjDecompressHeader3(decompressor(), ... );  // works as expected
tjDecompressHeader3(decompressor, ... );    // preferred way of doing it
```

I am pretty sure that this is achievable but I somehow can't find anything about how to do it.

Comment: Care or rule of 3/5/0.` std::unique_ptr` with appropriate Deleter might be used.

Comment: Would it be better to wrap also functions in the class and not expose the C class at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want I think is a conversion operator .... something that looks like

```
operator const tjhandle & () const { return m_tjInstance; }
```

you will then be able to call your function as

```
tjDecompressHeader3(decompressor, ...)
```

More information can be found here:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I was looking for. Great, thanks!